# Constructor initialization and object corruption

Tags: c++, constructor

I have the following class structure, which initially threw a segfault. I have fixed the problem, but don't fully understand why the code initially through a segfault. I had a class `B`, a subclass of `A`, which,
after `A` initialised an object (`InternalA`) in the initialisation list
of the constructor, called a `Run()` method, which called a method on `InternalA` (`InternalA.Start()`) before calling a blocking method (`io_service_.Run()`), and so `B`'s constructor never actually returned.

A separate thread would then try to access `B`, and call `B->SendMsg()`, but
all of `InternalA`'s internal state would be corrupted. I fixed the problem by removing the blocking `Run()` method call from the constructor, and calling it afterwards.

Code shows me that the `InternalA` object does indeed get correctly initialised, but when calling `b->SendMsg`, `InternalA` is completely corrupted.

The issue that, using the `new` operator, the "real" address only gets assigned to the `B*` pointer after the constructor is returned (even though, when I check the address of b in the main thread, it is no longer null). If I instead malloced `B`, and subsequently called `*b = B()`, would it still be an issue, or would this then be architecture specific?

```
class B: public A
{    
    B(): A(arg1, arg2) { Run(); }
};

class A {

   A(): InternalA()... {}

   Run() {
       InternalA.Start();
       // Method does not terminate
       io_service_.Run();
   }
};

class InternalA {

   InternalA(): io_service_(), map_(), id_(5) {}

   void Start() {
        std::cout << connections_.size() << std::endl;
   }

   void SendMsg() { 
        std::cout << connections_.size() << std::endl;
   }

   private:
      boost::asio io_service_
      std:map<X,Y> map_;
      int id_;
};

int main() {
 B* b = null;
 std::thread t([&b] {b = new B()}); // Run() method gets called
 usleep(200000);
 b->SendMsg(); // All objects in InternalA are corrupted (point to invalid addresses
}
```

Comment: There is no thread in your "example" (it does not compile). So if the constructor does not return the program will never SendMsg().

Comment: Constructor, should just do that - construct (initialize the state of) the object.

Comment: edited to add the thread. Agreed that the initial code is not correct and dangerous, but my understanding is that the "new" first allocated the memory address  (in which InternalA has already been setup) before returning control, much like malloc() followed by *B=B() would. Right now it looks like the address that B is pointing to is not valid at all.

Comment: Where is `b` declared/initialized in `main` ? The one in the lambda in local to lambda body.

Comment: But the `new B()` never returned: `new` allocates memory, calls the constructor, and then, only after the constructor has returned, returns. Since the constructor never returns, `new B()` too never returns and the `b` variable is never written to with the pointer to the created object — it hasn't finished being created!

Answer (score -1):

Before you can assign a value to `b`, that value has to be computed first. In your case, this computation (`new B()`) never returns, so you read uninitialized contents of the `b` in another thread.

Also, "a separate thread would then try to access B"? Without any checks organized to see if that "B" is actually there? You will have many hard-to-find bugs with such an approach.